# What's turning on my Logitech webcam?

Tags: video, webcam

I have a Logitech C920 webcam and after I use it for any type of video chat (whether it's in Slack, Skype or any other video chat service) the light on the webcam stays on until I restart my computer.

Is there a way to see *what* is causing the webcam to either actually be on or *appear* to be on?

I'm running macOS 10.12.5 on a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13", Early 2015).

Comment: 10.12.4 is the latest version of macOS you cannot be running 10.12.5 at this point.

Comment: @alljamin Beta program